# Adding images to EditText from Custom IME

Tags: android, emoji, ime, custom-keyboard

I'm working on a custom keyboard for Android, and I'm running into a problem. I need to either be able to output ASCII characters from the keyboard (i.e. ∅, ⌲, ⌓, etc), or be able to add images to the selected EditText from my keyboard. I know this is possible because Emoji does it with their keyboard. They have found a way to add images to any EditText, whether they created the EditText or not.

Does anyone have any idea how they accomplished this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this thread during some research and ended up elsewhere. Yes it is now possible to send images/GIF's to EditText's via a custom IME using the new **CommitContent** API introduced in 7.1 with backward compatibility till API level 13 - Honeycomb.

Quote from :
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/image-keyboard.html#how_it_works

[image]

> With Android 7.1 (API level 25), the Android SDK includes the Commit
>   Content API, which provides a universal way for IMEs to send images
>   and other rich content directly to a text editor in an app. The API is
>   also available in v13 Support Library as of revision 25.0.0. We
>   recommend using the Support Library because it runs on devices as
>   early as Android 3.2 (API Level 13), and it contains helper methods
>   that simplify implementation.

I tested this with the latest update of hangouts and it works!.

Sample code here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.1-samples.html#img-kbd-ime

I have merged the main app and the IME app code to a single project and here it is : https://github.com/satheeshwaran/ImageKeyboard-Android/tree/master

**UPDATE:**

I have published two apps using this API and I think they are doing good,

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.theweekendparty.indianmemekeyboard

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.theweekendparty.indiangifboardbollywood

Comment: When this question was posted and the answers were posted, that API hadn't been released. It's true, it's now possible.

Answer (score 2):

After many hours of pouring over blogs, Stackoverflow, and the rest of the internet, I've discovered that it's essentially impossible to add a custom image to an EditText unless you own that EditText.

All was not lost however. After looking through documentations on UTF-8, ASCII, and other character sets, I've discovered that all the characters I needed were in UTF-8. I simply output the unicode value using:

```
InputConnection inputConnection = getCurrentInputConnection();
inputConnection.commitText(text, 1);
```

and it correctly appears in the EditText. All the characters being added by other keyboards (i.e. stock Android, Emoji, etc.) appear in the UTF-8 character set.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CompoundDrawables` to add images to your `EditText`. You can add them through XML by `android:drawableBottom android:drawableRight android:drawableLeft android:drawableTop`. You can also use `Spannables` for displaying images inline with text inside `EditText`. See here [Spannables](http://blog.ostebaronen.dk/2013/02/adding-images-to-textview-and-edittext.html) and here [Displaying emoticons in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3341702/displaying-emoticons-in-android/4302199#4302199).

Comment: That's all fine and dandy, if I had access to the EditText itself. From what I can see, from the InputMethodService I've created, there is no way to actually access the selected EditText. I already know how to add images to an EditText. I need to be able to push them to an EditText that I don't own.

Comment: You should have access to `InputConnection` through which you can pass `Spannables`.

Comment: Tried that. The drawables never make it to the EditText.

Comment: Hmm, many discussions on SO about this topic. See particularly this [Emoji](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24645786/is-it-possible-to-add-animated-emoji-in-android-messaging). It seems that all you have to do is to simply send the encoded bytes of emoji through InputConnection then the smiling face should appear in the edit box.

Comment: Ok, I understand that. Any ideas about how to send those encoded bytes through? Do you have to subclass BaseInputConnection? Is there another method on InputConnection for sending byte data?